# How do we prove that $H$ is non-decreasing in each argument?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, copula

Suppose $S_{1},S_{2},\ldots,S_{n}$ are nonempty subsets of $\overline{\textbf{R}}$, and $H$ is grounded and $n$-increasing function whose domain is given by $\text{Dom}(H) = S_{1}\times S_{2}\times\ldots\times S_{n}$. Then $H$ is non-decreasing in each argument.

This is part of my self-studying on the theory of copulas. I have solved the problem when $n = 2$, but I am not able to prove it in the multivariate case. Precisely, this is the problem: prove that
\begin{align*}
H(\textbf{t}_{1}) \leq H(\textbf{t}_{2})\quad\text{when}\quad x < y,
\end{align*}
where $\textbf{t}_{1} = (t_{1},\ldots,t_{k-1},x,t_{k+1},\ldots t_{n})$ and $\textbf{t}_{2} = (t_{1},\ldots,t_{k-1},y,t_{k+1},\ldots,t_{n})$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question is unclear in present form.  The assertion you are trying to prove is that $H$ is non-decreasing in its $k$th argument.  Since you already say that $H$ is non-decreasing in each argument, it is unclear what premises you are using (side from the function being grounded).  Please be clear about what you are willing to assume about $H$ to begin with.

Comment: I think it has happened a misunderstanding. The property of being $n$-increasing is not the same as being non-decreasing in each argument. In fact, it means that the $H$-volume is nonnegative for every $n$-box $B = [\textbf{a},\textbf{b}]\subseteq[0,1]^{n}$, that is to say, $V_{H}(B) \geq 0$,